# Intel wireles 3165 WIFI adaptor not found on Ubuntu 18.10 (DELL Inspiron)

Tags: 18.10

I recently ugraded from ubuntu 16.10 to 18.10 LTS, but since the upgrade i  some how cannot connect to the wireless wi-fi unless i use a usb.
i have tried several methods to no avail.
some of the things i have tried include:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

output:

```
~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for chiefsamurai: 
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 79
       serial: 7c:67:a2:27:69:1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.1.0-050100rc2-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.8.104 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 memory:d2100000-d2101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 07
       serial: 64:00:6a:fd:f7:0a
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:17 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d2004000-d2004fff memory:d2000000-d2003fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx0c5b8f279a64
       serial: 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC Ethernet Device ip=192.168.8.100 link=yes multicast=yes
```

i did run this

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

the output was:

```
~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:4410]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

i even tried:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep Network
```

output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
```

then i checked if it was blocked
with

```
rfkill list all
```

the result was

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

when i did run

```
uname -r
```

i thought maybe mit was an outdated version so i followed a tutorial to upgrade to 5.1
now it looks like this when i run `uname -r`

```
5.1.0-050100rc2-generic
```

which if i enable secure boot it wont boot but shows an assigned signature error.
then update my /lib/firmare by copying the iwlwifi-7265-13 files ucode files, still my wifi doesn't work.
Please help i really need to get my wireless wifi to work.

Update:
@heynnema when i run `grep -i iwlwifi /var/log/syslog*`

i get this:

```
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar 29 18:25:03 chief-nechi-samurai kernel: [   20.203138] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar 29 18:25:03 chief-nechi-samurai kernel: [   20.412914] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar 29 18:25:03 chief-nechi-samurai kernel: [   20.659364] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar 29 18:25:03 chief-nechi-samurai kernel: [   20.681102] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 7c:67:a2:27:69:1a
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar 29 18:25:03 chief-nechi-samurai kernel: [   25.785034] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar 29 18:25:04 chief-nechi-samurai NetworkManager[1223]: <info>  [1553873104.6885] rfkill0: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver iwlwifi)
```

update 2:
@heynnema below is the output i got

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces</code>
```

output:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
```

as for

```
cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
```

output

```
cat: '/etc/netplan/*.yaml': No such file or directory
```

and for

```
resolvectl
```

result was:

```
 LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.8.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.8.1
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 4 (enx0c5b8f279a64)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.8.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.8.1
          DNS Domain: ~.

Link 3 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (enp3s0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

also tried

```
 sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up
```

and

```
sudo ip link set wlp2s0 up
```

problem still exisits

update 3:
as for

```
dpkg -l *netplan*
```

i got

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  netplan        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  netplan.io     0.40.2.2     amd64        YAML network configuration abstra
```

to answer your questions:
it wasn't a clean install, 
it was an upgrade and i encountered some errors since it lost power in the middle of the upgrade.
i fixed some how but since then the wireless wasn't working.
but everything i need for work seems to be working fine for now (hopefuly nothing comes up).

update #4:

i did install the .yaml files.

when i now run

```
cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
```

i get the file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

update #5:

after creating the .yaml file

i did:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
```

got this

```
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:5991): DEBUG: 17:13:02.875: Processing input file /etc/netplan/config.yaml..
** (generate:5991): DEBUG: 17:13:02.876: starting new processing pass
** (generate:5991): DEBUG: 17:13:02.876: Generating output files..
(generate:5991): GLib-DEBUG: 17:13:02.876: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
```

and as for:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

was succesful

now rebooting

Comment: Unfortunately you loaded a pre-release kernel on your system. You should boot to a prior version and then remove 5.1.0-050100rc2-generic, or use ukuu to do that.

Comment: `grep -i iwlwifi /var/log/syslog*` to search the syslog for clues to your problem.

Comment: @heynnema i have updated my with the output.

Comment: Show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `resolvectl`.

Comment: You can try `sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up` or `ip link set wlp2s0 up`.

Comment: @heynnema updated the results. thanks for helping

Comment: Please don't put [SOLVED] in the title or the solution inside the question. The Green check mark (✅) next to the correct answer is sufficient and marks the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and make it look like this...

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Reboot, and recheck `sudo lshw -C network` and make sure device `wlp2s0` isn't disabled. Retry wireless connections.

---

Due to problem(s) during your 18.10 upgrade, your `/etc/netplan` doesn't have any .yaml files in it. There should be at least one file there with the contents of (*if you're going to use NetworkManager instead of networkd*)...

`sudo pico /etc/netplan/config.yaml` # create/edit the .yaml file

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

`reboot` # reboot and verify operation

---

Lastly, boot to an older kernel than `5.1.0-050100rc2-generic` and then remove kernel `5.1.0-050100rc2-generic`, by using ukuu or whatever method you wish. That's an unstable "release candidate".

Comment: Man you are a life saver, it did work after i rebooted. it works fine now, Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @NechiMichael glad it's working for you now. Remember to apply the last two items.

Comment: i did switch to an older kernel i have  ```Linux 4.20.17-042017-generic
``` using ukuu (as you suggested)

Comment: @NechiMichael what about the .yaml file?

Comment: still no such file or directory, do i have to create the file

Comment: @NechiMichael  Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *netplan*`. Was this a clean install, or an upgrade? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: i have updated my answer as you asked. thank you

Comment: @NechiMichael yes, something did go wrong during the upgrade. I've edited my answer to help you create the missing .yaml file and use netplan commands.

Comment: i have updated my answer with the .yaml files

Comment: @NechiMichael did you use the 3 commands after creating the file?

Comment: no i did not see any command it just went straight to a file editor so i just added the lines

Comment: @NechiMichael there are 3 commands to do after creating the .yaml file. See my answer.

Comment: i see,  about sudo netplan --debug generate and apply. got it, i have already updated my question

Comment: @NechiMichael Good! Because of the problems during your upgrade, if you encounter new/other problems with 18.10, you may have to reinstall it.

Comment: thanks for all the help, lets hope nothing comes up.